# insufficient frame rate detected from Kinect

Tags: kinect

I have a Kinect 2 that runs at a framerate around 5-7 FPS (sometimes it peaks at 15 fps)

The system is an HP laptop, G3 i7-6820HQ, 8 gb memory, with an intel graphics 530 and an Nvidia Quaddro M1000M on Windows 10 Enterprise. As far as I can tell the system should be powerful enough to run the kinect at a better framerate. I've run the kinect on a another machine equipped with just an intel GPU, and it runs at a similar framerate, so I'm suspecting that it doesn't utilize the NVIDIA GPU.

I've followed the steps for multi-gpu systems outlined here:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/20dbadae-dcee-406a-b66f-a182d76cea3b/troubleshooting-and-common-issues-guide?forum=kinectv2sdk

but without any effect

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
It seems to me that the kinect is indeed using the nvidia card:
[image]

Any other ideas?

Comment: Not sure, it sounds like a multi-GPU system issue like you suspect. I have a system with GeForce GTX 860M that can run the Kinect 2 at 30 FPS, so I think something like the Nvidia Quaddro M1000M should be able to perform similarly (at least judging from benchmarks). Maybe there's GPU downclocking involved (automatic or by the manufacturer) to keep the laptop cool.

Comment: Maybe you can investigate which graphics card is in use with tools like CPU-Z and GPU-Z, and monitor the clocks of the GPUs. For example, see something like this post: [How do I determine which graphics card I'm using?](https://superuser.com/q/268901/895583)

Comment: thanks @sonny. I'll give it a try and report back.

Comment: As I understand, the frame rate for the raw frames coming out of the sensor on the Kinect would be much higher as it is the hardware frame rate. Due to software post processing of the raw frames, the perceived frame rate on a host PC (such as the one you are using) would be lesser. Can you tell how exactly you are measure the frame rate in your software application ?

Comment: Yes, I used the kinect configuration verifier from the kinect sdk

Comment: Consider posting your question in another stack site as this is not a coding related question.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a problem with my frame rate. I was plugged into a low-speed USB port on my computer. Simply switching to a high-speed USB port solved the problem.